# jQuery DataTable, each row stuck at first row

Tags: jquery, datatable

I´m looping a datatable with an active filter.
That works fine, except the first filtered element ist the first row of the Table.

Here´s my loop:

```
var array = [];
$('#tbl').DataTable().rows(0, {search: 'applied'}).data().each(function (value, index) {
    array.push([value[0], index]);
});
console.log(array);
```

`array` should fill with all the rows of datatable, but it contains only first row.

Comment: what is your issue with datatable?

Comment: When i filter my DataTable for a column i want to got all listed rows. That´s working fine. But when the first element of the datatable passes my filter, my loop push´s only that first row in my array, and not all 2+ rows which are displayed.

Comment: I beleive `$('#tbl').DataTable().rows(0, {search: 'applied'}).data()` has only one row. That's why `array` contains only one element.

Comment: The DataTable show´s me more rows than my `array` at least. However, if i use another filter for another column which doenst contain the first element of my datatable my array fills with all elements displayed in the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

i changed `$('#tbl').DataTable().rows(0, {search: 'applied'}).` to 
`$('#tbl').DataTable().rows({search: 'applied'}). ...` and it worked ..

example: https://jsfiddle.net/nrL75jef/

Comment: Due to `rows(0,...` it was giving only one row..as I said.....I beleive $('#tbl').DataTable().rows(0, {search: 'applied'}).data() has only one row. That's why array contains only one element.

Comment: Yeah ... but it worked .. sometimes with more than row. That´s why.